# WebSocket connection never fully established when traffic is routed through Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, websocket, routes, cloudflare, ws

I use a service called glitch.me to host my Node.js project, and they only allow you to open one port internally. At the moment, my Node.js server can only handle HTTP requests, but glitch.me proxies my traffic for me, effectively allowing the client to communicate indirectly using HTTPS. My project heavily relies on the use of WebSockets, and they work perfectly when accessing it directly via example.glitch.me (the url provided by glitch.me). However, I need to connect this project to my custom domain (example.xyz), all traffic of which is proxied through Cloudflare. However, when attempting to establish a WebSocket connection through my custom domain (in other words: via Cloudflare), the socket connection is never established.

Now, I realise that this sounds very specific, but I think it's possible to generalise here:

**WebSockets work:**

- client => glitch.me => my backend
- client => A => my backend

**Webockets don't work:**

- client => cloudflare => glitch.me => my backend
- client => A => B => my backend

**Note:** HTTP/HTTPS still works for both domains.

I added logging on the server-side every time a WebSocket connection was established, and sure enough the server receives the connections! However, the client is never notified and in Chrome Developer tools it shows that the request never completed. Remember, everything is working perfectly when the traffic is not routed through Cloudflare.

I have full understanding for the fact that it may be impossible for you to resolve my issue with the information given to you, but I'm not asking you to do so. My question is simply this: where does the problem lie? Does the response from my backend get stuck somewhere along the way and doesn't reach all the way through? I have contacted both glitch.me and Cloudflare and they have both confirmed that they fully support WebSocket traffic.

What is the most probable cause of my problem? From there I could probably fix it!

Edit: I uses the [ws package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) on the backend and standard JavaScript WebSockets on the frontend.

Comment: do you have any nginx reverse proxy ?

Comment: please use https://socket.io/ -- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io , it is more reliable in my experience

Comment: Have you figured out the solution?